# eBay Shopping API Pagination

Tags: php, pagination, ebay-api

I was wondering if anybody could help me out with a bit of a pagination issue in my store. Using pajinate, I initially put this together but it seems to be bugged. I'd like to add a 'previous' and 'back to beginning' as well as a 'next' and 'last page' button. I tried implementing the 'back to beginning' and 'previous' buttons first but they aren't working correctly. If anybody could help me out a bit that would be fantastic. On a side note, i have this set to display a range of 10 numbers at a time, but each time i click on a higher page number it appends with 4-5 more numbers any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated as well.

```
<?php
// find out total pages

$totalpages = $resp->paginationOutput->totalPages;
echo "Total Results: ";
echo $totalpages.' pages ';
// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['pgno']) && is_numeric($_GET['pgno'])) {
   // cast var as int
   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['pgno'];
} else {
   // default page num
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   // set current page to first page
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $entriesPerPage;

/******  build the pagination links ******/
// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
if(null!=$queryString){
//  echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?$queryString&currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
}else{
//  echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
}
   // get previous page num
 //  $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   // show < link to go back 1 page
//   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if

// range of num links to show
$range = 10;

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range)  + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $currentpage) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<strong>$x</strong>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='".add_url_param('pgno',$x)."'>$x</a> ";

      } // end else
   } // end if
} // end for
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had prev page commented out, and using $_GET['currentpage'] rather than $_GET['pgno'], this worked for me:

```
<?
$totalpages = 10;
if (isset($_GET['pgno']) && is_numeric($_GET['pgno'])) {
// cast var as int
$currentpage = (int) $_GET['pgno'];
} else {
// default page num
$currentpage = 1;
} // end if

echo $currentpage;
echo "/".$totalpages;
echo "<br />";

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
// set current page to last page
$currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
 // if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
 // set current page to first page
 $currentpage = 1;
}   // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $entriesPerPage;

/******  build the pagination links ******/
// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
// show << link to go back to page 1
if(null!=$queryString){
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?$queryString&pgno=1'><<</a> ";
}else{
  echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pgno=1'><<</a> ";
}
// get previous page num
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
// show < link to go back 1 page
 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pgno=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if

// range of num links to show
$range = 10;

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range)  + 1); $x++) {
// if it's a valid page number...
  if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
    // if we're on current page...
     if ($x == $currentpage) {
       // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
       echo " [<strong>$x</strong>] ";
    // if not current page...
    } else {
       // make it a link
       echo " <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pgno=$x"."'>$x</a> ";

     } // end else
   } // end if
 } // end for
 ?>
```

Comment: to be more clear: I changed  <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> to  <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pgno=$prevpage'><</a>

Comment: this works for me. re-adjusted totalpages. there are more pages, but i only want 10 numbers to display at a time, when you choose another page notice that it appends with more. my next problem is getting a next and last button in there. 

http://valueguide.pga.com/file-exec/f/ebaystore/h/true

Comment: only problem, when i choose another page it reverts to general results as opposed to the current filtered results your're on.

Answer (score -1):

```
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $entriesPerPage;


if ($currentpage > 1) {

?where comes this variable
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it doesn't even look it could be good as a comment. StackOverflow questions (and answer) are not meant to be a medium for discussing things. You either know the answer or you don't. If there's something you want to ask the user, consider posting a direct comment to the question. Also, please give a look at the StackOverflow Help section.